# What is best practice to write such a PHP code

Tags: php

This code is from my Kohana project. How to make it more beautiful?
Should I use try-catch instead? How not to write exit() two times?

```
public function action_index()
{
    $id = $this->request->query('id');
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $ticket = ORM::factory('ticket')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->find();
        if (!empty($ticket)) {
            $event = ORM::factory('event')
                ->where('id', '=', $ticket->event_id)
                ->find();
            if (!empty($event)) {
                $this->template->ticket = $ticket->id;
                $this->template->name = $ticket->name;
                $this->template->event = $event->title;
            } else {
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try asking this on [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code becomes more readable (IMHO) in this style:

```
public function action_index()
{
    $id = $this->request->query('id');
    if (empty($id)) {
        return; //or exit() if you really need it
    }

    $ticket = ORM::factory('ticket')
        ->where('id', '=', $id)
        ->find();
    if (empty($ticket)) {
        return; //or exit() if you really need it
    }

    $event = ORM::factory('event')
        ->where('id', '=', $ticket->event_id)
        ->find();
    if (empty($event)) {
        return; //or exit() if you really need it
    }

    $this->template->ticket = $ticket->id;
    $this->template->name = $ticket->name;
    $this->template->event = $event->title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually use the one-liner form of if statements, but in this case I think they help readability a lot.

```
public function action_index(){
    $id = $this->request->query('id');

    if (empty($id)) return;

    $ticket = ORM::factory('ticket')
        ->where('id', '=', $id)
        ->find();

    if (empty($ticket)) exit();

    $event = ORM::factory('event')
        ->where('id', '=', $ticket->event_id)
        ->find();

    if (empty($event)) exit();

    $this->template->ticket = $ticket->id;
    $this->template->name = $ticket->name;
    $this->template->event = $event->title;     
}
```